# Designing coupling between objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I need some advice about how to design my code.

[image]

My system has several `HW` (Hardware) consisting a lot of data for the process to use. `HW` in turn has several `Channel` which also have a lot of data.

In addition there some data unique to each `Plant` (`PlantHW` and `PlantChannel`). These are not so much data in them, and they are not used as frequently as `HW` and `Channel`. What `Plant` to be used in the process is selected by the user before starting the process, and does not change during the run. But the user can cancel the process, and select another `Plant`.

My question is how to bind `HW` with `PlantHW` and `Channel` with `PlantChannel` in a good way (direction does not matter)? I want it to be loosely coupled, have OK performance, and easy to understand.

I'm also not sure whether it is best to iterate all the `HW` or `PlantHW`. The pros and cons for the two alternatives:

**Iterate `PlantHW`**

- Pros: Most logical as the process is for a specific `Plant`
- Cons: It is `HW` that contains all interesting data, and it feels like a detour to constantly go through `PlantHW`.

**Iterate `HW`**

- Pros: `HW` contains all interesting data
- Cons: Not as logical
- Cons: The process have to know the selected `Plant` to get the corresponding `PlantHW`/`PlantChannel`.

I want advice about how to design this.

**Edit**

The 6 classes are containing settings and process data that are used by the process. They are read from a file (by binary serialization) then the program is started.

- `System` - Common system settings
- `Plant`  - The process can run against multiple plants. This class contains data that are unique for each plant.
- `HW`     - Contains settings and process data for a hardware equipment.
- `PlantHW`     - Contains settings and process data for a hardware equipment for a specific plant.
- `Channel`     - Contains settings and process data for a channel in the hardware equipment.
- `PlantChannel`     - Contains settings and process data for a channel in the hardware equipment for a specific plant.

Eg I want to be able to do this (if I select the alternative to iterate `HW`):

```
void DoOperationsOnAChannel(HW hw, Plant selectedPlant)
{
   // plantHw data is not often used
   // var plantHw = GetPlantHW(hw, selectedPlant); 

   foreach(var channel in hw.Channels)
     //Do operations based on hw, plantHw and channel
}
```

Or (if a select the alternative to iterate `PlantHW`)

```
void DoOperationsOnAChannel(PlantHW plantHw)
{
   var hw = GetHW(plantHw);
   foreach(var channel in plantHw.Channels)
     //Do operations based on hw, plantHw and channel
}
```

Comment: both options state "iterate a2". I assume the first is a typo. just saying ;)

Comment: and are you able to rename a1,a2,b1,b2 into meaningful names? kinda hard to read this way

Comment: Ups, thank you for paying attention to my misprint :-)
I agree, it's a bit difficult to follow the text as it is now. The names used in the program is very technical, and I could not think of any good names to use in the text. Can you think of any good names, I love to change it.

Comment: what would definitely help is adding some short description per class (responsibilities). to me it sounds that processes own plants, but your diagram depicts something else. thus, I misread what you are trying to say. (could me me tho)

Comment: so you have two types of processes? a and b. and for each type of process you can specify specific settings? System is something that should be shared for all processes since they contain generic settings. What do you have now?

Comment: I have updated a bit, and given a little better name.
I understand that it was a bit unclear, and I understand that you misunderstood me. There is only one process.

Comment: To fill in the question marks: the correct relationship would be inheritance. (`public class PlantHW : HW` and `public class PlantChannel : Channel`).

Comment: It is a way to looking at it.
But all the settings from HW must be the same in all instances of PlantHw. You could use static, but it does not feel like a good solution.

Comment: Could it be an idea to for example let HW and PlantHW inherit from the same interface and letting PlantHW returns data from HW. All PlantHW then returned from the same HW. The problem with that is that it then becomes difficult for if HW is changed. The alternative is to let PlantHW returns a reference to HW, but it violates LoD. Are there other options I have not thought of?

Comment: Very unclear question. I don't understand what the application does and what is your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well could not get very clear idea on your question, but as per my understanding, u need to have a plant and plant channel associated with a hardware and channel respectively. In my view you should have a plant interface and your hardware class should get the the instance of plant injected to it through interface. This gives you flexibility to change any of your implementation even at run time. Same applies to even Channel class.